# SSIS packages within SQL Server Agent and File Server: advantages - disadvantages

Tags: ssis

All,

I have considerable number of SSIS packages, and need to configure it on PRODUCTION environemnt. Just want to know the advantages and disadvantages of configuring and running SSIS packages within SQL Server Agent over File Server. All the packages are designed in SQL Server 2005.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The following site provides a description of the pros and cons of each:
http://pragmaticworks.com/community/blogs/nayanpatel/archive/2008/11/13/what-are-the-advantages-disadvantages-of-storing-ssis-packages-to-msdb-vs-file-system.aspx

This is summarised in the following table:

```
Functionality        Best in File System    Best In MSDB
Security                                    Yes
Backup and Recovery  Yes    
Deployment           Yes    
Troubleshooting      Yes    
Execution Speed      Yes                    Yes
Availability         Yes
```

Where i work we have a number of different shipping environments, and shipping tool. We also have the need to pass in connection strings (for each shipping stage), so have to worry about other means by which we encrypt the data. Placing everything in the file system is so much easier for us.

Comment: Stop chasing points instead help build the community. Points will follow... :)